# SQLAlchemy ORM: Why row[0].attribute instead of just row.attribute on select results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Why did the creators of SQLAlchemy decide to return `rows` from `select` statements with ORM tables (like `User(Base)`) in `tuple`s with the first result being what you'd expect the normal result being?

For example, if your query is this:

```py
user = session.execute(select(User)).first()
```

Why did they decide this:

```py
user_name = user[0].name
```

is better than this:

```py
user_name = user.name
```

by default?

Comment: Neither of those answered my question.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66974718/2144390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this was done to make the API more consistent with the core api.  Also this makes a single argument compatible with multiple arguments, ie `select(User)` and `select(User, Company.name).join(User.company)` both return namedtuple-like rows.  There is some explanation in the docs: [rowproxy-is-no-longer-a-proxy-is-now-called-row-and-behaves-like-an-enhanced-named-tuple](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html#rowproxy-is-no-longer-a-proxy-is-now-called-row-and-behaves-like-an-enhanced-named-tuple)

**added more doc links based on comments**

Note that it seems there are a few helper methods to make this usage easier, [`session.scalar`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html?highlight=scalars#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.scalar), [`session.scalars`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html?highlight=scalars#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.scalars), [`scalar`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=scalar_one#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalar) and [`scalars()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=scalars#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalars) to achieve your intended usage.

Multiple ways to perform this task:

```py
# This is probably the most clear for a single result.
user = session.scalar(select(User))
user = session.scalars(select(User)).first()
user = session.execute(select(User)).scalar()
user = session.execute(select(User)).scalars().first()

# for looping without needing to unpack 1-tuple
for user in session.scalars(select(User)):
    print(user)
```

Compared to this type of usage

```py
user, = session.execute(select(User)).first()
user, company_name = session.execute(select(User, Company.name).join(User.company)).first()
```

Comment: FYI, the preferred usage for SQLAlchemy 1.4+ is `session.scalars(select(User))`. It is functionally equivalent to `session.execute(select(User)).scalars()` but is a bit more compact. (We are in the process of updating the documentation to reflect this.)

Comment: @GordThompson Will `scalar_one()` work in the same way? Like `session.scalar_one(select(User))` or is this only for `.scalars`? EDIT: Nvm, looks like those  are for different things.

Comment: @ZackPlauché - Right. `session.scalars(select(User)).one()` or `session.scalars(select(User)).first()` is what we would use for ORM.