# SQLAlchemy select : How to assign a column name to an ORM entity?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given the SQLAlchemy 1.4 query below, I am selecting an ORM entity, `models.Person` with two additional calculated columns, `prev` and `next`.

```py
  @pytest.mark.wip
  @pytest.mark.asyncio
  async def test_sqlalchemy(people: AsyncSession) -> None:
      session = people

      query = (
          select(
              models.Person,
              Bundle(
                  "navigation",
                  sa.func.lag(models.Person.cursor)
                  .over(order_by=models.Person.cursor)
                  .label("prev"),
                  sa.func.lead(models.Person.cursor)
                  .over(order_by=models.Person.cursor)
                  .label("next"),
              ),
          )
          .where(models.Person.id > "26744d86-1918-4f67-92a0-e7ca12043721")
          .order_by(models.Person.id.asc())
      )

      iterator = await session.execute(query)
      rows = iterator.all()

      print(f"person = {rows[0][0]}")
      print(f"next={rows[0].navigation.next} prev={rows[0].navigation.prev}")
```

When I execute the query and access a resulting row, I can access the next and prev columns via a named attribute, e.g. `rows[0].navigation.next`. This was possible using the `Bundle` feature in SQLAlchemy.

However, I can only access the `Person` ORM entity attributes via column index, e.g `rows[0][0].surname`. Is it possible in SQLAlchemy to assign an ORM entity a column name so that I can do something like `rows[0].person.surname`?

I have tried assigning a `Bundle` to the ORM entity, e.g. Bundle("person", models.Person). However I get an error: `AttributeError: 'AnnotatedTable' object has no attribute '_label'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved based on information given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71819808/12152982). The method was to retrieve each column into a variable, e.g

```
person, navigation = rows[0]
      print(f"person = {person.surname}")
      print(f"next={navigation.next} prev={navigation.prev}")
```

*Full listing solution*

```py
  @pytest.mark.wip
  @pytest.mark.asyncio
  async def test_sqlalchemy(people: AsyncSession) -> None:
      session = people

      query = (
          select(
              models.Person,
              Bundle(
                  "navigation",
                  sa.func.lag(models.Person.cursor)
                  .over(order_by=models.Person.cursor)
                  .label("prev"),
                  sa.func.lead(models.Person.cursor)
                  .over(order_by=models.Person.cursor)
                  .label("next"),
              ),
          )
          .where(models.Person.id > "26744d86-1918-4f67-92a0-e7ca12043721")
          .order_by(models.Person.id.asc())
      )

      iterator = await session.execute(query)      File not indexed
      rows = iterator.all()

      person, navigation = rows[0]
      print(f"person = {person.surname}")
      print(f"next={navigation.next} prev={navigation.prev}")
```